# Sum input from JOptionPane

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, sum

The code I have is pretty clear, all it does so far is prompt the user for 10 inputs of integers, which I am trying to sum. I want to make it so that after each number is entered, it's added to the sum variable. How can i do this? 
Here's the code.

```
int x = 10;
int i = 1;
int maxNumber = 100;
int sum = 0;

while (i <= 10) {
    x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter one grade at a time."));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `sum += Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter one grade at a time."));`  ?

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work because it prompts the user more than 10 times. It must prompt the user ONLY 10 times, while summing each integer entered by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
while (i <= 10) {
    x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter one grade at a time."));
    i++;
    sum+=x; //This line will keep the total
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and netbeans tells me it's "not a statement"

Comment: @PetroKo Which statement?

Comment: sum+=x;         <----------------------

Comment: @PetroKo Do you have `int sum = 0;` declared somewhere

Comment: Yes, at the very beginning.

Comment: @PetroKo Update your question with the code, using this line.

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work!! Thank you! I will be accepting this answer.